# Return JSON into javascript object from Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there a way to populate a client side javascript object, for use in visualisation libraries like D3 or Paper.JS via ORACLE APEX, without the ORDS REST service?

i.e. can I use the javascript API, or PL/SQL (APEX_JSON?) for example to run a query, and return into a client side javascript object the json response?

I know how to return JSON into a PL/SQL Dynamic Content region for example using PL/SQL (see below), but if I just want the data to get returned into a client side javascript object - whats the process?  The query below does output formatted JSON into the REGION output, but I just want the json in memory as a javascript array, ready to pass to another javascript library.

```
declare 
l_cursor sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
   OPEN l_cursor for SELECT A.UID, 
cursor(SELECT PREFERRED_NAME FROM DIM_PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCT_ID = A.PRODUCT_ID) as PRODUCTS from ARIEL.MARKETED_PRODUCT A WHERE STATE = 'C';
   APEX_JSON.write(l_cursor);   
END;
```

Regards

Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do an AJAX request and have it return JSON into a client-side javascript object. There's two parts to this - PL/SQL on the server side, and javascript on the client side.

On the server side, the easiest way is to set up an On-Demand Process that returns your JSON. It sounds like your block above works fine for that.

On the client side, you can either use the [Application Express JavaScript API](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/javascript_api.htm#AEAPI29529) or jQuery (the APEX JS stuff is just a convenience wrapper around jQuery).

Example client-side AJAX call:

```
apex.server.process ( "MY_PROCESS", {
  x01: "test",
  pageItems: "#P1_DEPTNO,#P1_EMPNO"
  }, {
 success: function( pData ) { ... do something here ... }
  } );
```

In this example, `pData` is the JSON returned from your On-Demand Process - whatever you want to do with it, you should do in the success callback function.

Three parameters are being sent to the On-Demand Process named `MY_PROCESS`: `x01`, which can be accessed in PL/SQL as `apex_application.g_x01` or [`:APP_AJAX_X01`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/concept_sub.htm#HTMDB30285), and two page items, which are added to session state and can be accessed the usual way (`:P1_DEPTNO`, etc).

See also this article on [how to test an On-Demand Process](http://www.inside-oracle-apex.com/how-to-test-an-on-demand-process-used-for-ajax/).